# Dotnetnuke hijacks IIS Default Documents?

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

After upgrading an older site to Dotnetnuke 9.2, all URLs to default documents fail (non-dnn folders).

For example:

- DnnSiteDomain.com/**podcasts**    *<-- Fails*
- DnnSiteDomain.com/**podcasts/default.asp**  *<-- Works*
- DnnSiteDomain.com/**podcasts/default.aspx**  *<-- Works*
- DnnSiteDomain.com/**podcasts/default.html**  *<-- Works*

This worked fine for years, and now all of a sudden doesn't work anymore. DNN is intercepting the URL and sending it to 404 (instead of the default IIS file), is there a setting somewhere to fix this?

Comment: Brad, what'd you do, upgrade from Pre DNN 7.1? :P

Comment: @ChrisHammond pretty much yeah, but didn't see this coming. Any fix?